# p5js rotate shapes with noLoop()

Tags: javascript, rotation, p5.js

I'm trying to rotate a rect and line using the following:

```
push();
    rect(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, 500, 250);
    line(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
    rotate(45);
pop();
```

This code doesn't rotate the objects though. I also tried:

```
push();
    rotate(45);
    rect(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, 500, 250);
    line(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, windowWidth, windowHeight / 2);
pop();
```

with the same result

I am using noLoop() so it only draws once, but I'd like the page to load with the shapes already rotated. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you provide the code with the setup and variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in order to first rotate, you have to translate the object first.
For better understanding:

https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rotate

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9sgjuh-CBM

Assuming you have specified angleMode() in your setup function...

```
translate();
rotate();
rect();
line();
```